# getting Cannot read property 'command' of undefined error in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, angular, typescript

Im using typescript and I get this error in the chrome console:

> Error in event handler for (unknown): TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'command' of undefined
>       at chrome-extension://somethingsomethingsomething/js/hooks/content.min.js:1:345

does someone know whats the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> chrome-extension://somethingsomethingsomething/js/hooks/content.min.js:1:345

One of your chrome extensions has gone wonky. `somethingsomethingsomething` is the id of the chrome extension. Also looking at `content.min.js` might give you some hint on *which extension is being a bad citizen*.